# java genericps tuples en windows

Tags: java, interop

He encontrado  una libreria jar para trabajar con tuplas en java
Pero que yo sepa parece estar basado en importar librerias de c++ de gcc al java
¿funcionaran en windows?
No me he atrevido a ponerlo en marcha por miedo a romper mi instalacion de eclipse
con java fx

```
import java.util.*; 
import org.javatuples.*; 
 class GfG { 

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        // Create Septet 
        Septet<String, String, String, String, String, String, String> 
            septet = new Septet<String, String, String, String, String, String, String>( 
                "Septet", "Sextet", "Quintet", "Quartet", "Triplet", "Pair", "Unit"); 

        // Print the Septet 
        System.out.println("Septet: " + septet); 

        // Create Octet from Septet 
        Octet<String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String> 
            octet = new Octet<String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String>( 
                "Octet", 
                septet.getValue0(), 
                septet.getValue1(), 
                septet.getValue2(), 
                septet.getValue3(), 
                septet.getValue4(), 
                septet.getValue5(), 
                septet.getValue6()); 

        // Print the Octet 
        System.out.println("Octet: " + octet); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Por favor agrega un [mcve] para poderte ayudar

Comment: El código que puiste no significa que forsozamente usa alguna librería de `C++`, Yo solamente veo que hicieron una pseudoestructura de datos con [Generics](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_generics.htm).

Comment: Acá hay otras librerías que puedes usar para multimapas, https://www.techiedelight.com/implement-map-with-multiple-keys-multikeymap-java/

Comment: Acá puedes ver el código de como se implementa un multimapa en Java https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/jacoco/org.apache.commons.collections4.map/MultiKeyMap.java.html

Comment: Ahora en cuestiones más de fondo... ¿Por qué querrías tener una séptupla o un octeto en vez de un objeto? ¿Necesitas a fuerza una llave compuesta para indexar y no puedes representarla en el paradigma orientado a objetos?

Comment: gracias la doy por contestada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por si alguien ocupa una respuesta concreta a esto, no, la librería `javatuples` no usa en ninguna parte de su código [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) es 100% Java, lo puedes verificar viendo la totalidad de su código al ser un proyecto open source en [github](https://github.com/javatuples/javatuples), conforme viene referenciado en su [página principal](https://www.javatuples.org/).